# Remove non-printable character from a string in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you remove non-printable characters from a String in Flutter/Dart.

```
var c ="Maintain central project files (hard copy and electronic) for administration.â¢Perform a wide variety of administrative duties"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to remove?  If it's the `â¢` characters, those are certainly *printable* (i.e., they are not control characters).  If `â¢` are [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), then decode the string with the correct encoding first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to only keep base ascii characters, you could try something like this:

```
  var c =
      "Maintain central project files (hard copy and electronic) for administration.â¢Perform a wide variety of administrative duties";
  var clean = c.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^A-Za-z0-9().,;?]'), ' ');
  print(clean);
```

and you get:

```
Maintain central project files (hard copy and electronic) for administration.  Perform a wide variety of administrative duties
```

Tweak the regex to include more or less characters, depending on how much cleanup you want (say you could remove all the punctuation marks, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I built:

```dart
/// Replaces all non-printable characters in value with a space.
/// tabs, newline etc are all considered non-printable.
String replaceNoPrintable(String value, {String replaceWith = ' '}) {
  var charCodes = <int>[];

  for (final codeUnit in value.codeUnits) {
    if (isPrintable(codeUnit)) {
      charCodes.add(codeUnit);
    } else {
      if (replaceWith.isNotEmpty) {
          charCodes.add(replaceWith.codeUnits[0]);
      }
    }
  }

  return String.fromCharCodes(charCodes);
}

bool isPrintable(int codeUnit) {
  var printable = true;

  if (codeUnit < 33) printable = false;
  if (codeUnit >= 127) printable = false;

  return printable;
}
```